# How do I fully clean my project?

Tags: android, c, compilation

I have fixed an error in my code, but every time I call `ndk-build` the same error is STILL there. I have called `ndk-build clean` fifteen times at least, but I have had no luck. I have gone into my project and deleted my `.o files`. What should I do?

Notice the spelling of `initilized/initialized`:

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I allways manually just empty the gen and bin folder.

Comment: Do those folders affect the C code? My java code isn't the problem, its the C code I'm trying to use with the NDK.

Answer (score 1):

In Eclipse, menu *Window* -> *project* -> *Clean*.